# How long has it been a custom to bow at the mention of the Incarnation?

Tags: church-history, prayer, liturgy, incarnation

I asked a question a few years ago and it was mentioned in a anecdote concerning the devil from 1374 that people were genuflecting at the mention of the incarnation

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3619/4

In chat, it was lamented that early Christians seemed to not have this quite figured out for a lot longer than they ought to have had the Evangelists made the Hypostatic Union a tad clearer.

So, given that Tradition (big T) is not always something easily gleaned from the writings of learned men, do we have any better sense of how long Christians have been genuflecting or showing particular reverence to the mention of God becoming man?

It seems to have been a sticking point for St. Athanasius, I can only assume his mother instructed him well on such matters.

Comment: This is an interesting question, which might benefit from you providing examples of how Athanasius showed reverence (or spoke reverentially) at mention of the Incarnation. Can you enlarge on this?

Comment: See [my comment to another question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/89487/do-muslims-pray-like-christians-should#comment248697_89487) which may point to a much older origin: multiple prostration seven times a day (at canonical hours).  So the question is whether the current genuflections / deep bow were adaptations from much older Oriental/Western rites.

Comment: You probably will not get a canonical answer to this. If you would like I could make a more roundabout answer on the historical subject of bowing within the Catholic Church.

Comment: @ken I don't expect a canonical answer just hints. The answer isn't terribly useful except in connection with the Incarnation.